# In react-native - how to float elements in new line when they can't fit into one?

Tags: reactjs, layout, react-native, react-native-flexbox

From the [example here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flexbox.html) I'm wondering if it's possible to float items into new line when they can't fit into one?

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red'}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'green'}} />
  <View style={{width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'blue'}} />
</View>
```

The `blue` coloured item should be in new line. Is it possible with flexbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply `flexWrap` to root container style.

```
<View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
```